# Attribute textAllCaps has already been defined

Tags: android

I am trying for the first time to write and compile an app for Android. So far everything went well until I discovered that my developer mates have lost the key for signing the APK file which makes a whole new app the only option as somehow changing the package name does not work with eclipse Projects. That is not all that bad because the app needed restructuring anyway. 
Now that I am done and wanted to try out the new app I run into an error message that I cannot resolve. 
I know that there are questions concerning my error message but they did not help in resolving the problem.

The project was generated in Android Studio but the classes are taken from the eclipse generated project. They make no problem and everything got sorted out. 
The error I am confronted with tells me:
      Error:(1) Attribute "textAllCaps" has already been defined

I have not messed with the values.xml file the error occurs in!

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile files('libs/sqlite4java.jar')
```

This is what the compile part of my build.gradle file looks like. I am not importing any of the libraries that are making trouble in the other questions which is why I post this one.

I would be very grateful if anyone took the time and was able to help me. 
Thank in you advance. 
If you require any additional information please let me know I'll be happy to provide it.

Comment: Can you post the code with the error?

Comment: could I share you the project because the file itself is too big in terms of characters
The link would be :(https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5v0kk64370rgedr/AADv5_iUCkgp_n66W1SRgWI8a?dl=0)
The path is :RoRoSchedule/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/res/values/values.xml

Comment: will take a loot at it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found the problem. The AppCompat library defines its own attribute with the name textAllCaps, so do you in your attr file in your project. Remove this line and it should work.

```
<attr name="textAllCaps" format="boolean" />
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I fixed that problem and run into 5 new ones :D Thats fine though thats why we program right because we love puzzles.